# How to port code from Perforce repository to TFS

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have inherited maintainence responsibilty for C# solution that is currently under source control in Perforce. I want to port the code to Team Foundation Server. Is there a painless way to do this, or is it a case of manually getting the head from Perforce and adding it to TFS?

(it might be useful to say that I know nothing about Perforce and not much about TFS :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by [this thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/866c5ee6-0d95-4e38-aab6-aae306a88596/) there are no off the shelf tools available, but you could try [these consultants](http://www.aitgmbh.de/index.php?id=perforce_migration_p4&L=1); they were linked via MSDN so I assume they're approved by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use a tool for the migration. History is important, so the migration tool must be able keep history. I suggest that you migrate into a **Import** folder. From this you can branch into the new TFS structure. You might change the branching structure/pattern when changing to TFS.

[image]

Perforce and TFS is very similar regarding the source control. However I recommend that you do some reading about SCM patterns. In order to get a repository that has a structure that supports your branching requirements and a project folder structure that can organize your project, it is necessary to document your SCM strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but was hoping that you might know of a tool?